# SELECT epoch timestamp bigger then my variable

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Why is this

```
SELECT strftime('%s', timestamp,'localtime') from locationLog WHERE strftime('%s', timestamp,'localtime') > 999999999999999999 ORDER BY _id DESC
```

return any outputs when all of my rows have a lower value in "timestamp"

in my case the query above returns

```
1334735588
1334735349
1334734317
1334734178
1334734172
and so on...
```

it returns my whole table.

if I switch `>` to `<` it returns nothing.

I guess I'm trying to compare different type of variables or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a `text` value with a `integer` value, so sqlite casts the `integer` value to `text`, and does a string comparison:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%s', '2002-02-02', 'localtime');
1012611600
sqlite> select typeof(strftime('%s', '2002-02-02', 'localtime'));
text
sqlite> select typeof(999999999999999999);
integer
sqlite> select strftime('%s', '2002-02-02', 'localtime') > 999999999999999999;
1
sqlite> select cast(strftime('%s', '2002-02-02', 'localtime') as integer) > 999999999999999999;
0
```

As shown above, the solution is to cast the returned value of `strftime` to some numeric type.

Comment: I already figured it out with the exact same solution but Ill be allowed to answer myself only in a couple of hours due to my low reputation. so you beat the clock. (also you educated me about typeof) THANK YOU very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you're on a 32-bit platform and the fact that you have used an integer larger than 2147483647 has caused you to hit a variation on the ["Year 2038 Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Try using `2147483647` as the number you compare against in your query.

This will continue to work until 2038, by which time you will presumably be hosting your application on a 64-bit platform (or maybe even 128- or 256-bit by then!)